# Sorting String word without using built-in String api

Tags: java

How to sort a String Word without using built-in String method in Java. I am confused to use `toCharArray()`, because it is in `Java.String` package and I want to sort the string word without using any `String API`.

Comment: ??? Can you be more specific, what do you want to do, implement your own method for sorting Strings ?

Comment: So `java.lang.String` isn't used at all? Then how are the strings represented? If it's a `String` you cannot access its content without using its methods.

Comment: I want to display this String I/p: "String is a word" and the o/p: "a is String word". Yes I want to implement my own method for sorting.

Comment: how `a is String word` is sorted ?? can you explain ??

Comment: Sorry my bad... I don't want to use String class methods...I want to use class but not methods inside this String class. Because without using String class we can't accept any String in my method.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use toCharArray(), you can try something like this,

```
    public static String sortString(String inputString)
    {
        // convert input string to Character array
        Character tempArray[] = new Character[inputString.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
            tempArray[i] = inputString.charAt(i);
        }


        // Sort, ignoring case during sorting
        Arrays.sort(tempArray, new Comparator<Character>(){

            @Override
            public int compare(Character c1, Character c2)
            {
                // ignoring case
                return Character.compare(Character.toLowerCase(c1),
                                        Character.toLowerCase(c2));
            }
        });

        // using StringBuilder to convert Character array to String
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(tempArray.length);
        for (Character c : tempArray)
            sb.append(c.charValue());

        return sb.toString();
    }
```